# P value for interaction term in mixed effects models using lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, p-value, lme4-nlme

I'm analysing some behavioural data using `lme4` in `R`, mostly following [Bodo Winter's excellent tutorials](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorials.html), but I don't understand if I'm handling interactions properly. Worse, no-one else involved in this research uses mixed models, so I'm a bit adrift when it comes to making sure things are right.

Rather than just post a cry for help, I thought I should make my best effort at interpreting the problem, and then beg your collective corrections. A few other asides are:

- While writing, I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794729/test-for-significance-of-interaction-in-linear-mixed-models-in-nlme-in-r), showing that `nlme` more directly give p values for interaction terms, but I think it's still valid to ask with relation to `lme4`.
- `Livius'` answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63464/is-this-an-acceptable-way-to-analyse-mixed-effect-models-with-lme4-in-r) provided links to a lot of additional reading, which I'll be trying to get through in the next few days, so I'll comment with any progress that brings.

---

In my data, I have a dependent variable `dv`, a `condition` manipulation (0 = control, 1 = experimental condition, which should result in a higher `dv`), and also a prerequisite, labelled `appropriate`: trials coded `1` for this should show the effect, but trials coded `0` might not, because a crucial factor is missing.

I have also included two random intercepts, for `subject`, and for `target`, reflecting correlated `dv` values within each subject, and within each of the 14 problems solved (each participant solved both a control and an experimental version of each problem).

```
library(lme4)
data = read.csv("data.csv")

null_model        = lmer(dv ~ (1 | subject) + (1 | target), data = data)
mainfx_model      = lmer(dv ~ condition + appropriate + (1 | subject) + (1 | target),
                         data = data)
interaction_model = lmer(dv ~ condition + appropriate + condition*appropriate +
                              (1 | subject) + (1 | target), data = data)
summary(interaction_model)
```

Output:

```
## Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
## ...excluded for brevity....
## Random effects:
##  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
##  subject  (Intercept) 0.006594 0.0812  
##  target   (Intercept) 0.000557 0.0236  
##  Residual             0.210172 0.4584  
## Number of obs: 690, groups: subject, 38; target, 14
## 
## Fixed effects:
##                                Estimate Std. Error t value
## (Intercept)                    0.2518     0.0501    5.03
## conditioncontrol               0.0579     0.0588    0.98
## appropriate                   -0.0358     0.0595   -0.60
## conditioncontrol:appropriate  -0.1553     0.0740   -2.10
## 
## Correlation of Fixed Effects:
## ...excluded for brevity.
```

ANOVA then shows `interaction_model` to be a significantly better fit than `mainfx_model`, from which I conclude that there's a significant interaction present (p = .035).

```
anova(mainfx_model, interaction_model)
```

Output:

```
## ...excluded for brevity....
##                   Df AIC BIC logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)  
## mainfx_model       6 913 940   -450      901                          
## interaction_model  7 910 942   -448      896  4.44      1      0.035 *
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

From there, I isolate a subset of the data for which the `appropriate` requirement is met (i.e., `appropriate = 1`), and for it fit a null model, and a model including `condition` as an effect, compare the two models using ANOVA again, and lo, find that `condition` is a significant predictor.

```
good_data = data[data$appropriate == 1, ]
good_null_model   = lmer(dv ~ (1 | subject) + (1 | target), data = good_data)
good_mainfx_model = lmer(dv ~ condition + (1 | subject) + (1 | target), data = good_data)

anova(good_null_model, good_mainfx_model)
```

Output:

```
## Data: good_data
## models:
## good_null_model: dv ~ (1 | subject) + (1 | target)
## good_mainfx_model: dv ~ condition + (1 | subject) + (1 | target)
##                   Df AIC BIC logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)  
## good_null_model    4 491 507   -241      483                          
## good_mainfx_model  5 487 507   -238      477  5.55      1      0.018 *
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Comment: Check this question for more info on p-values in `lme4`: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118416/getting-p-value-with-mixed-effect-with-lme4-package

Comment: Using lmerTest::anova() will give you the anova tables with p-values for each term. That would allow you to directly examine the interaction, rather than comparing overall models. See this answer to the question @Tim linked to: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/118436/35304

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see too much to say here.  I think you have done a good job.

There are several ways that people have discussed to test effects and get p-values for complicated mixed effects models.  There is a good overview [here](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq).  The best is to use computationally intensive methods (bootstrapping or Bayesian methods), but this is more advanced for most people.  The second best (and best convenient) method is to use a likelihood ratio test.  That is what `anova()` (technically [?anova.merMod()](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/functions/merMod-class)) is doing.  It is important to only use a likelihood ratio test of models that were fit with the full [maximum likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood), rather than [restricted maximum likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_maximum_likelihood) (REML).  On the other hand, for your final model, and for interpretation, you want to use REML.  This is confusing for many people.  In your output, we see that you fit your models with REML (this is because the option is set to `TRUE` by default in `lmer()`.  That would mean that your test is invalid, however, because this is such a common mistake, `anova.merMod()` contains a `refit` argument which by default is set to `TRUE`, and you didn't change it.  So the foresight of the package developers has saved you there.

Regarding your strategy for unpacking the interaction, what you did is fine.  Just bear in mind that the interaction uses all the data for its test.  It is possible to have a significant interaction but have neither of the stratified tests be significant, which confuses some people.  (It doesn't seem to have happened to you, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I am a novice myself, and follow the advices from Zuur et al.. I use `lme` from the `nlme` package instead of `lme4` when I need to add a hierarchical error structure to an otherwise linear model. My response might be way off.

Two comments:

(1) I am not sure it makes sense to test `condition` in the subset when `appropriate==1` only. If you want to obtain p-values for the main effects, you can use `Anova` from the 'car' package:

```
require(car)
Anova(M,type="III")# type III Sum of Squares. M was fitted using method=REML
```

If you want to resolve the interaction, you can run paired comparisons directly (?) or do what you did but on both subsets (i.e. also with the subset where `appropriate==0`).

(2) You might want to select your error structure first instead of assuming `(1 | subject) + (1 | target)` is the best error structure. From what you wrote, I gather that `condition` is a within subject factor, while `appropriate` is either a between-subject or a between-target factor. You might want to add slopes for within-subject and/or within-target factors, for example: `dv ~ condition + appropriate + (1+condition | subject) + (1 | target)` adds a random slope for the within-subject factor `condition`. No slopes are needed for between-subjects/targets factors.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Won't `Anova` just pretend the within-subject and -target correlations aren't there though? The reason I repeat the analysis with only data where `appropriate==1` is that a number of the materials used were shown to be problematic a post-test, thus 'inappropriate'. Finally, I've not used random slopes for the simple reason that the model fits better without them.