# Getting P value with mixed effect with lme4 package

Tags: mixed-model

I have problem with getting p value from my mixed model,
library(lme4)

```
DWR<-lmer(DWRm2~Growth.stage+Se.application+Growth.stage:Se.application+(1|Block),data=Sub1)
summary(DWR)
```

before I used this model and I got p value with summary my model but now I can't get it, I have just t value

Comment: `library(lme4); help(pvalues)` gives some discussion.

Comment: @Smilig In spite of the similar titles the content seems to be completely different, since the other question seems to be focused on `memisc` not `lmer`; further, the answer there would be useless for this Q.

Answer (score 28):

I'm pasting the information from `help("pvalues",package="lme4")` here.

Users who need p-values have a variety of options. In the list below, the methods marked `MC` provide explicit model comparisons; `CI` denotes confidence intervals; and `P` denotes parameter-level or sequential tests of all effects in a model. The starred (*) suggestions provide finite-size corrections (important when the number of groups is <50); those marked (+) support GLMMs as well as LMMs.

- likelihood ratio tests via `anova` (MC,+)
- profile confidence intervals via `profile.merMod` and `confint.merMod` (CI,+)
- parametric bootstrap confidence intervals and model comparisons via `bootMer` (or `PBmodcomp` in the `pbkrtest` package) (MC/CI,*,+)
- for random effects, simulation tests via the `RLRsim` package (MC,*)
- for fixed effects, F tests via Kenward-Roger approximation using `KRmodcomp` from the `pbkrtest` package (MC)
- `car::Anova` and `lmerTest::anova` provide wrappers for `pbkrtest`: `lmerTest::anova` also provides t tests via the Satterthwaite approximation (P,*)
- `afex::mixed` is another wrapper for `pbkrtest` and `anova` providing "Type 3" tests of all effects (P,*,+)
- `arm::sim`, or `bootMer`, can be used to compute confidence intervals on predictions.

  When all else fails, don't forget to keep [p-values in perspective](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=905).

Answer (score 17):

p-values in lme4 are deliberately not listed by default, see:

- Bates (author of lme4) on [p-values in linear mixed models](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/094765.html)
- or [here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-hypotheses)
- see also:
  [How to get an "overall" p-value and effect size for a categorical factor in a mixed model (lme4)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95054/how-to-get-the-overall-effect-for-linear-mixed-model-in-lme4-in-r)

There are some "approximations" but better just forget about p-values in lmm (or generally forget about them because they "measure" mostly the sample size).

Comment: Could you briefly summarize the points made? Links can die, which would render an otherwise valuable answer almost useless.

Comment: (I do realize that might be quite a difficult task, but it would make your answer substantially more useful, particularly if both links were lost. The links should of course remain; the extensve discussion is highly valuable.)